# Adding key mapping

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am getting an error saying: `TypeError: me.target is null`
My function recieves as first parameter an array containing some ids on some elements (and as 2nd parameter, a string containing the shortcut keys).

I am getting the element like this: `var target = Ext.getCmp(array[k]);`
Running this in a console, the target does get created, and show as object with several properties, and here including id. So I don't know why Extjs says that target is null. Anyone can help out?

```
      function addKeyMap(array, key) {
             for(var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                    var target = Ext.getCmp(array[k]);                       

                    var map = new Ext.KeyMap ({
                        target: target.id,
                        key: key.charAt(k),
                        fn: function() {
                            alert("Parent works!!!");                                                                         
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you run the addKeyMap function too early, when the components are not created / loaded yet.

That would explain why Ext.getCmp() works later on using the console.

Encapsulate the addKeyMap function call in an Ext.onReady like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

addKeyMap([...]);

});
```

That way you can be sure, that every component got instantiated / the page finished loading when you run the addKeyMap function.